# getting only the path out of `type -p prog` command

Tags: command-line, shell-builtin

if I run

```
nrolland@mactoasty ~ $ type -p skhd   
skhd is /usr/local/bin/skhd
```

I can't compose it nicely with other command like

```
nrolland@mactoasty ~ $ la `type -p skhd`      
ls: is: No such file or directory
ls: skhd: No such file or directory
lrwxr-xr-x  1 nrolland  admin    29B Jun  4 09:35 /usr/local/bin/skhd -> ../Cellar/skhd/0.2.2/bin/skhd
```

What is the cleanest way to get only the second part ?
(I am using zsh if that's any help)

Comment: Are you using `zsh`?

Comment: yes, using zsh. adding that to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `command -v skhd` instead:

```
ls -l "$( command -v skhd )"
```

[The `command` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/command.html) is a POSIX standard utility, and by using its `-v` flag it will output the path to the given utility, if it is found in `$PATH`, unless it's a function, alias or shell built-in utility.

Comment: technically that's the answer. though the zsh is the best fit for my particular environment. I will note this as the answer if people search for the same in the future.

Answer (score 3):

In `zsh`, `type -p` is verbose by default. From `man zshbuiltins`:

```
   type [ -wfpamsS ] name ...
          Equivalent to whence -v.
```

If you don't want the verbosity, you can use `whence -p` instead:

```
% type -p g++    
g++ is /usr/bin/g++
% whence -p g++  
/usr/bin/g++
```

Comment: I note the `command` answer as such if other people search for the same question in the future, as it's more portable, but thank you again